# FTDI USB-to-serial converter does not show up as ttyUSBx

Tags: 14.04, usb

I have a FTDI USB-to-serial converter connected to my Ubuntu 14.04 system. When I enter

> lsusb

I can see it is connected:

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC
```

When I enter

> dmesg | grep tty

I get:

```
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.499958] 00:0b: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[  342.011015] usb 3-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

However, this ttyUSB0 is from another FTDI chip, which is inside the Ubuntu system.

How do I get the /dev/ttyUSB* for the external FTDI chip?

Comment: After connecting the converter, look at the corresponding lines in `dmesg` without grepping something. There might be some hint what is happening. Usually, this device should work with libftdi. For more hints, see http://ftdi-usb-sio.sourceforge.net/#sec6

Comment: FWIW; my [Mightyboard](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:16058) -based 3D-printer with USB-serial port never connected to the PC when running 14.04 LTS, but it did immediately after having installed 16.04. I don't remember all the tweaks and tricks that I tried to get it running with 14.04.  I had the idea to try and run pure RS232 from the printer to a  a pure USB/FTDI-based serial port - the same problem, plus the printer FW didn't support this.

Comment: Something to try: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/268510 , https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/251424

Comment: Problem is fixed. Device ttyUSB0 is the one I need to use. Because of my misunderstanding of command dmesg I thought ttyUSB0 was an internal device, but because of your tips I found that ttyUSB0 is indeed the external serial device I wanted to connect to. Everybody thanks for your suggestions.